# Passportjs forget logged user after second refresh

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, passport.js

I took this [example.(easy-node-authentication)](https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication)
I changed some things to work out a single page, so i build post request with JQ:

```
$(document).on('click','#submitLoginIDButton ', function (){
    $.post( "/login", { "email" : $("#emailLoginID").val(), "password" : $("#passwordLoginID").val() })         
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Change some routes to below:

```
app.get('/',
    function(req, res) {
        if (req.user) {
          var logged = true;
        } else {
          var logged = false;
        }
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title : "No More Miss",
            userStatus : logged
        });
}); 

app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local-login'),
function(req, res) {
    res.send({ status: 'OK', user: req.user });
});
```

Login works and if i refresh it show that i am logged in but after second refresh its lost, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `resave` property to `false`.

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false }))
```

I don't know what's cause to this problem, but it's work anyway.

Try read more information at https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave.

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate passport's session ? If you do not initiliaze it, the auth info will be lost after you refresh the page.

From [passport.js configure page](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) :

> If your application uses persistent login sessions, passport.session()
>   middleware must also be used.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));  
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

> Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is
>   recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use
>   express.session() **before** passport.session() to ensure that the login
>   session is restored in the correct order.

Comment: sessions is enabled and initialized like you writed, and middleware is existing, isLoggedIn, from the example in file app/routes.js. Result remains the same.

Comment: As mentioned by @Waldo, everything is same, but still the error persists.